SQLAlchemy: Wheres on joined table results in duplicate join on same table
I have defined my models like:
class Service(Base):
    __tablename__ = "services"

    service_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint(
            "service_id",
            name="services_pkey",
        ),
    )

class SMP(Base, common_models.PostgresBaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "smp"

    service_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey(
            "services.service_id",
            ondelete="CASCADE",
        ),
    )
    service: Mapped["Service"] = relationship(lazy="joined", innerjoin=True)

When I do a query like
stmt = stmt.where(
    Service.service_id == "672f12736ea63f38f35fd9dd",
)
stmt = stmt.options(
    joinedload(SMP.service, innerjoin=True),
)

It results in a query like
SELECT smps.abc, services_1.xyz, ...
FROM smps 
JOIN services AS services_1 
ON services_1.service_id = smps.service_id, 
services # Why this???
WHERE services.service_id = $1::VARCHAR // <-- not using the joined table in where?

Seems like it does not know the Service.service_id ==  should refer to the joined table?

I think this comment applies: "How joinedload() in particular achieves this result of not impacting entity rows returned in any way is that it creates an anonymous alias of the joins it adds to your query, so that they can’t be referenced by other parts of the query. " from The Zen of Eager Loading

@snakecharmerb Ah nice! You can post your comment as answer. Also, from there I need to use contains_eager to tell SQLAlchemy the join is to load the relationship. See Routing Explicit Joins/Statements into Eagerly Loaded Collections
